# unity 3d socket-io [SyntaxError: Unexpected token o] with fpanettieri/unity-socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, github, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I’m importing the whole fpanettieri/unity-socket.io asset into my unity project.

Afterwards, as instructed;

I’m dragging prefab to my scene.

Configuring the url to: “ws://xxxx:1234/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket”

Ticking the autoconnect on the prefab’s inspector.

Then sending our server a check command:

```
private IEnumerator CheckServer()
{

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

    Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    data["action"] = "CHK";
    data["deviceid"] = ""+SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier;

    JSONObject[] list = new JSONObject[1];
    list [0] = new JSONObject (data);

    list [0] = new JSONObject((string)(new JSONObject (data)).ToString());


    JSONObject objs = new JSONObject(list);

    Debug.Log ("JSN:" + objs.Print ());
    socket.Emit("CHK",objs);

    yield return null;

}
```

On the NodeJS server side we have:

```
var io = require('socket.io')({ transports: ['websocket'] });
var activeSocketUserCount = 0;
io.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('disconnect', function(socket){
    activeSocketUserCount--;
    console.log( '      -[',activeSocketUserCount,'] user active')
    //console.log( '-', 'a', '[', 'user is' ,'] disconnected -> socket :', socket.id);
});

socket.on( 'error', function ( data ) {
    console.log( data );
});

// checking server.
socket.on( “CHK”, function ( data ){
    var parsedData = JSON.parse( data )
    var clientAction = parsedData.action
    var clientHash = parsedData.hash
    socket.emit( “CHK”, JSON.stringify( { result: 'ok', action : clientAction, hash : clientHash } ) );
});
});

io.attach( 1234); // this code line runs after the mongodb database connection is secured
```

When a request sent client disconnects and we get the following error
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token o]

The last letter ‘o’ usually changes with ‘u’ or ‘s’ by the data we send.

What is this error related to? 
Any relations with the issue mentioned on the Git as “old JSONObject library is not parsed”
or is it something completely different?
Any kind of help is appreciated.

(Also to mention that, project works fine with the example server code both locally and on server.)